# azure active directory reqiring password instead of code

Tags: azure

I'm trying to authenticate a user and I made a azure active directory.

It was logging in with a code but now does password. I want it to use a code for login, how do I fix it to this setting.

Comment: Usually the one time code sent by email is only for guest accounts that are not in any Azure AD. Is that the case with your user?

Comment: that's probably what's happening thanks for pointing it out. 
I was so confused why it switched to password 30 minutes later. Have a good day!